# Create schema and tables when needed with spring boot while app is running

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an issue with creation of new schema while app is up and running. I managed to create a filter that switch between schemas to connect to the right one but now I would like to use Hibernate or Spring to create new schema inside current application. I am using MultiTenancyStrategy.SCHEMA approach.

In my Rest Controller I have method, designed for admins, to simply add a new app customer/schema. This method should take care of creation of schema, tables and everything. So far I managed to do everything by starting up another SpringBoot app as a process and wait for it to finish.

```java
            try (Statement stmt = dataSource.getConnection().createStatement();) {
                stmt.execute("CREATE SCHEMA "+instance.getDomain()+" AUTHORIZATION "+dbUsername+";");

                //execute java -jar schemacreator ...
                List<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();
                commands.add("java");
                commands.add("-jar");
                commands.add(dbCreatorPath);//database creator path to find an app we have to run
                commands.add(dbUrl);//arg 1 - url for the database
                commands.add(dbUsername);//arg 2 - db username
                commands.add(dbPassword);//arg 3 - db password
                commands.add(instance.getDomain());//arg 4 - name of the generated schema
                Process p = new ProcessBuilder(commands).start();
                if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    try(BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))) {
                        String line;
                        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println(line);
                        }
                    }
                }
                int exitValue = p.waitFor();
                log.info("Exit value of database creator tool: {}", exitValue);
                if (exitValue!=0) {//tables were created successfully
                    throw new RuntimeException("Exit value of db creator tool was not as expected but was "+exitValue);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            }
```

This is working ok since database creator has property spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto set on update, which create tables. Maybe it is important to know that I am using only one datasource.

So, is there any internal method/approach that could be used to execute creation of tables on just created schema? The best would be if annotated classes could be found on classpath automatically. Basically the same process that happens on SpringBoot startup where ddl is executed should happen here.

I am using:

spring-boot-starter-parent 2.1.1.RELEASE

spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 2.1.1.RELEASE

PostgreSQL

Any help or at least direction would be very helpful. Thanks!